# Android firewall? Blackhole? One IP unreachable

Tags: networking, firewall

I have a device, an ESP8266-like, connecting my automower to my wan.

If I hardcode the address to 192.168.1.48, it is accessible from my phone and my laptop, among others I guess.

If I hardcode the address to 192.168.1.44, it is **not** accessible from my phone, but still from my laptop.

I don't get pings back when pinging 192.168.1.44 from the phone, a traceroute end with the phone's own IP, as I do when I traceroute to an unreachable address.

In short, something on the phone seems to be blocking that particular IP. Rebooting the phone doesn't help.

The phone is a OnePlus 5, Android, OxygenOS 9.0.6

EDIT: all devices are on the same WiFi, Ubiquity devices.

Comment: Is you wan from some router or is that of phone's hotspot? What's the phone's IP address?

Comment: All devices on same ubiquity wifi network.

Comment: And what's your phone's IP? Anyone here won't be able to know what's going on on your device, unless you provide enough logs and info; how many hosts are on the network, what are their IP addresses, what does `ip -n` shows, what are the gateway IP and DNS IP, is the router DHCP or you do static configuration completely, can you ping your router from phone etc. Android doesn't have a restrictive firewall, but the routing is really complicated.