# Some local ipv4 hosts unreachable

Tags: networking

Periodically some hosts on my LAN (but not others) are inaccessible from my phone, both in chrome and pinging/tracerouting from termux.  These hosts are up at the time and accessible from other devices on the network.  On the phone the hostnames resolve incorrectly when I ping (presumably caching a previous result) and attempts to connect by ip fail as unreachable.  Other LAN hosts are always available.  There is no pattern (yet spotted) in which device becomes inaccessible or for how long.   The phone is connected only to the correct wifi network (dhcp) and there is only one dns server on my lan (which is not the default gateway).

How do I debug this?  `ip route` in tmux just returns the *phone's* ip address. `traceroute` likewise falls back to the phone.  A comment on [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214189/android-firewall-blackhole-one-ip-unreachable) mentions that 'android routing is really complicated'.  How do I find out where the packets are *actually* being sent?

The problem is annoyingly transient, but if I have some idea what to run next time it happens I might be able to get a handle on what's happening.  It seems to have begun recently, but I've been away for a few months and can't say *which* upgrade.  The phone is a Galaxy A10 running android 11.

Comment: So your "LAN" is just one subnet? Which one?

Comment: @Robert 192.168.0/24. It's just home stuff.  The local dns resolves `.lan` and queries something like 8.8.8.8 for anything else.